# Vba Excel macro copy cells on another sheet and in different positions

Tags: excel, vba

I have to create a macro in VBA. I'm really a newcomer in this, and I don't know really how to do it, but I have basic programming skills. I have to copy the salary of the people that go from column D to an indefinite number (because they can add later more people to the list).
If in column B finds numbers it has to copy the salary, code and name of the column corresponding to people until the end in the other sheet:

[image: sheet1]

It have to do something like this:

[image: sheet2]

This is my code:

```
Sub CopiarCeldas()

Dim i As Long, UltimaFila As Long, UltimaColumna As Long

Set Uno = Sheets("1")
Set Datos = Sheets("Datos")

lastRow = Uno.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 5 To lastRow
    'test if cell is empty
    If Uno.Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then
        Datos.Range("D" & i - 1).Value = Uno.Range("G" & i).Value
        Datos.Range("L" & i - 1).Value = Uno.Range("L" & i).Value
    End If
Next i
      End sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this.

You populate the array with the item numbers and the sheets name.

```
Sub CompareCopy()
Dim FirstSheet As Worksheet
Set FirstSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Define data sheet
Dim SecondSheet As Worksheet
Set SecondSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Define sheet to paste into
Dim lcol As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim lrowCompare As Long
Dim Val As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim arr() 'Define the array

arr() = Array(1, 12, 13, 32, 42, 48, 162, 178, 216, 316, 321, 789, 987, 995, 996, 997, 999) 'Set the array with all the item numbers you want to compare

lcol = FirstSheet.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Find last column in Row 5
lrow = FirstSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1, for column B
lrowCompare = SecondSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet2 for Column B

For k = 4 To lcol                                'Loop from Column D to last Column
    For i = 11 To lrow                           'Loop through ID column in Sheet 1
        Val = FirstSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value       'Get Item Value in Sheet 1
        For Each arrayItem In arr                'Loop through each element in Array
            If arrayItem = Val Then              'If array item is equal to Val then
                SecondSheet.Cells(lrowCompare, 3).Value = arrayItem 'Print array item
                SecondSheet.Cells(lrowCompare, 1).Value = FirstSheet.Cells(5, k).Value 'Print number
                SecondSheet.Cells(lrowCompare, 2).Value = FirstSheet.Cells(6, k).Value 'Print name
                If FirstSheet.Cells(i, k).Value <> "" Then 'If cell value is blank then ignore otherwise copy value
                    SecondSheet.Cells(lrowCompare, 4).Value = FirstSheet.Cells(i, k).Value 'Copy value
                End If
                lrowCompare = lrowCompare + 1    'Add 1 to row
            End If
        Next arrayItem
    Next i
Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data sheet is named Sheet1 and the result sheet is named Sheet2, you can try:

```
Sub test()

    Dim n As Integer 'n will represent the column at which you find the first people
    n = 4
    Dim m As Integer 'm will represent the row on your Sheet2
    m = 2

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    ' Loop on the people's name
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(6, n))
        ' Loop on items, 50 to be replaced by the row number of your last item
        For i = 11 To 50
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then
                ' Report people main salary
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                Cells(5, n).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Cells(m, 2).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                'Report people name
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                Cells(6, n).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Cells(m, 3).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                ' Report item code
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                Cells(i, 2).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Cells(m, 4).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                'Report item value
                Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
                Cells(i, n).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Sheet2").Select
                Cells(m, 5).Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                m = m + 1 'Iterate row counter
            End If
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        ' Next item for the same people
        Next i
    ' Next people
    n = n + 1
    Loop
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
End Sub
```